# How to set up emacsclient as default editor on Debian?

Tags: emacsclient, bash, debian

### What am I trying to achieve

I want to use `emacsclient` (not `emacs`) as my default text editor on Debian Buster.

### What have I tried so far

- Alternatives:

  ```
  > sudo update-alternatives --config editor`
  There are 3 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
    0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
    1            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
    2            /usr/bin/emacs       0         manual mode
  * 3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  ```

  Emacs is listed here, but when I choose `2`, and test using `git rebase -i HEAD~3` (in a git directory) it launches a new `emacs` instance.
- `$EDITOR` & `$VISUAL`:

  I added these 2 lines in my `.bashrc`:

  ```
  EDITOR="emacsclient -nw"
  VISUAL=emacsclient
  ```

  I can confirm the values are set but `git rebase -i HEAD~3` still opens a `vim`.  (This is despite [the fact the documentation saying that `$EDITOR` & `$VISUAL` are taken into account](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) )

---

How can I set my default editor to be `emacsclient`, both for terminal & GUI? (Preferably without changing my system in too many places)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why `.bashrc` solution didn't work.  I had to actually `export` the variables:

```
export EDITOR="emacsclient -nw"
export VISUAL=$EDITOR
```

---

I use `-nw` both for `$EDITOR` & `$VISUAL` since I don't want to involve my `emacs` frame as much as possible.